# Ip address server block is over ridding domain server block

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server and I have a domain listening on port 80. I also want to setup if a user enters the ip address of the server they get this static html page.

Right now my ip address server block which is

```
listen XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80
```

is overriding the domain server block how can I fix this? I tried using default_server but I thinking that putting an if statement would be the best. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to put IP address in `listen` directive? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#mixed_name_ip_based_servers

Comment: You should use `listen 80; server_name XX.XX.XX.XX;` for that

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks didn't know that a server_name could be an ip address. That worked! Can you answer it with that so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse `listen` directive with `server_name`.

`listen` is network level directive which makes nginx listen to some port and interface, while `server_name` is about what `Host` header will browser send.

So instead of `listen 12.34.56.78:80` you should use

```
listen 80;
server_name 12.34.56.78;
```

Also it's worth to read [how nginx process request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).